# compare the value from file in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files named file1 and file2, now i want to pick value from file1 and search it on whole file2, if record found then apply the operation on the file1 records else apply some other operation on file1 records.

file 1

```
a
s
d
f
g
```

file 2

```
q
e
r
a
g
```

earlier i was using like below

```
awk -F'|' '{if($1="abc" || $1="a") print ......}' file1
```

Now i have multiple values to compare and i have put the values in the file (abc,a.....)
but i don't know how to use it.

Please help

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to do this would be to store the values you are searching for in a hash and use it as a lookup table. Something like this might work for you:

*search.awk*

```
FNR==NR { 
  seen[$0]
  next
}

$0 in seen { 
  print $0 " is in file2"
  next 
} 

{ 
  print $0 " is not in file2" 
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f search.awk file2 file1
```

Output:

```
a is in file2
s is not in file2
d is not in file2
f is not in file2
g is in file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{print $0,($1 in a)?"Yes":"No"}' file2 file1

a Yes
s No
d No
f No
g Yes
```